# ssh tunnel with PuTTY won't close to Azure Jenkins VM

Tags: azure, jenkins, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I created a Jenkins Marketplace instance and used PuTTY to SSH. Now when I use exit and go to localhost:8080 , it's still Jenkins. I closed out of PuTTY with the 'x' button and it still doesn't close the tunnel.

edit
I restarted my computer and it worked, but now localhost:8080 doesn't work.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you want to browse the Jenkins, you make an ssh through putty with a tunnel of the port 8080. If you want to release the port 8080, you should close the browser for the Jenkins and then close the putty. And the port 8080 is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a local Jenkins instance that it kept directing to.